# How to do math calculation in python stored in json

Tags: json, python-2.7

Beginner of python and would like to know How to do the below math calculation in python and return the result as part of json result. Can someone help ?

**Math Calculation:**
Result = 66 + (6.23 * Weight) + (12.7 * Height) – (6.76 * Age)

**Actual Json Looks like:**

```
{
"User": [
    {
        "AGE": 54,
        "HEIGHT": 76,
        "WEIGHT": 254
    }
],
"details": [
    {
        "X": 54,
        "Y": 30.92,
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected Json after Math Calculation:**

```
{
"User": [
    {
        "AGE": 54,
        "HEIGHT": 76,
        "WEIGHT": 254,
        "ResultCalculated" : <value>
    }
],
"details": [
    {
        "X": 54,
        "Y": 30.92,
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has a json module which you can use for this.

```
import json

json_input = """

Your initial JSON as string

"""

data = json.loads(json_input)
```

Then you can access data as native Python data structures:

```
weight = data["User"][0]["WEIGHT"]
height = data["User"][0]["HEIGHT"]
age = data["User"][0]["AGE"]
```

Finally you can calculate the result and turn it back into a JSON string:

```
result = ... # Enter the calculation

data["User"][0]["ResultCalculated"] = result

json_output = json.dumps(data)
```